# Q2A Categories page to appear as Tree using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using Snowflat theme & like to customize 'categories' page to be displayed as Tree

E.g.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css-tree-menu-framework

Also, I would like to add a symbol (+) in front of categories having sub-categories.

URL : http://theupsconline.com/?qa=categories

How can I do this?
Q2A version: 1.7.4

Comment: I think this is may need JavaScript or Jquery!

Comment: I can override CSS too. If that is an option...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/JRwaXP

We use the :before to apply content like "+" or the bullets to an li

```
.li-with-subs:before {
```

Please do read the comment in front of the content property for the following class if you want to re style the tree verticle lines.

```
.tree:before,
.tree ul:before {
```

P.S. Jquery is required for this as there is not yet full browser supported ways for css to handle selective parent elments.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am looking for almost same thing, but for page http://theupsconline.com/?qa=categories. If you could give me CSS/JS for this page, that will be of great help. I will accept this answer.

Comment: If you apply the same classes and the js i provided in the answer to that page then you can achieve it. With little tweaking. I think you can work out you answer. To give you full solution could cost you my hourly rate :). I encourage you to work it out as it will help you to learn something.